# bc command not scaling numbers to decimal places

Tags: shell, bc

I am trying to scale my number calculation to one decimal place (with all applicable rounding) using the `bc` command in linux. This is my test expression:

`echo "scale 1; 90 - 70.333" | bc`

However, I end up with 3 decimal places:

`19.667` is the result.

Any idea how to use `bc` properly to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using

```
echo "scale 1; 90 - 70.333" | bc
```

Try to use

```
echo "scale 1; 90 - 70.333/1" | bc
```

That might do the trick.

Comment: Because the "scale" parameter is mainly used for division where the number of decimals won't depends of the user's input precision.

Comment: Ah interesting side effect. Thanks